# Firebase Cloud Messaging onMessage and setBackgroundMessageHandleraren't being executed properly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, twilio, notify

I'm implementing fcm for browser based notifications in a react web-application and the firebase-service worker has successfully registered. But whenever a message is sent, the receiver of the message throws a warning and no other logging. This warning appears every time the notification is sent to the other user.

Warning:

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-<PACKAGE>.js
firebase.js:1:839418
```

and my firebase service-worker:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase-messaging.js');


var config = {
apiKey: "a",
authDomain: "b",
databaseURL: "c",
projectId: "d",
storageBucket: "e",
messagingSenderId: "f"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
alert('AAAAH');
console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
// Customize notification here
const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    //icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
};

return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
//      return console.log('done');
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log('Oh No ' + e);
});
```

I've read that possibly there could possibly be a formatting issue with the JSON data being sent but I'm using Twilio Notify for the notifications and the notification is reading as sent on the Twilio Console.

Also here's the onMessage function in the Provider.jsx file

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
                        console.log('Message received. ', payload);
                        alert(payload.data.twi_body);
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.log('An error occured while setting up Message Event Listener. ', err);
                });
```

Comment: Did you get this solved at all? Did you find your `console.log` in the service worker was being called at least?